# How to run npm test after npm start in bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, dockerfile

In my docker file, I want to run test script inside it after app is up in Docker dev version. Problem is when I created a bash script and add like that, `test` script is not working.

Here is my package json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js src --out-dir lib --copy-files lib --plugins transform-react-jsx --presets es2015",
    "bundle": "./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js lib/client.js -o public/js/bundle.js",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run bundle && node lib/server.js",
    "test": "mocha ./src/*.test.js"
},
```

and here is bash script file

```
#!/bin/bash
npm start
npm run start

npm test
npm run test
```

Please let me know how to fix it, thanks much.

Comment: Not sure why you run each command twice in the script. Also where are you calling the script?

Comment: @smac89 I will call as `CMD ["/scripts/test.sh"]` Because for my test scripts, app is required to run first that's why that unit test could be able to test that app's api.

Comment: Is your issue fixed?

Comment: @Bsquare yap. Could u pls check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run build
npm run bundle
forever start ./lib/server.js

npm test
```

I've found solution that I need to install `forever` or `pm2` first.